# jQuery UI autocomplete different source

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I tried to use jQuery UI autocomplete. I have different autocomplete field in one page and I need to get data with different sources (different URL) depend to which autocomplete field is used. I know how can I get the typed data (request.term), but I can't find the way to get the selected field ID.

```
$(".ac").autocomplete({
             
     source: function(request, response) {       
       id = '??? the actually used field #id ???';
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/admin_/sql/autocomplete/"+id, 
         data: "test=...",
         async: false,
         success: function(data) {  
           
           } 
       });
     },
     search: function() {
      // 
    },
     focus: function() {
      // 
      return false;
     },
     select: function(event, ui) {
      //
      return false;
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

almost took my half day ...

`$(this).attr('element').attr('id')`

Comment: The success function is missing the `response(data);`, so the return json or list appear in the combobox